# Find Percentage of Task Completed

Tags: python, python-3.x, celery, percentage

Is there any way to find the percentage of the task completed provided the ID in celery? Something like:

```
>>> a4654.percentage()
    93%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No there is not.** Celery does not handle the task logic. You write that. That means that Celery is unable to know how much work a task has completed. However, you could implement this as part of your task logic.